# Flutter Amplify Datastore not dispatching ready

Tags: flutter, synchronization, aws-amplify, datastore

I’m unable to get DataStore to dispatch ready.  After synching all models from the cloud, it stops after dispatching syncQueriesReady and never gets to dispatching ready.

This happened once before when I had corrupted data in the cloud which prevented sync reaching ready, but this time I’ve already deleted all data in all models in the cloud through Amplify Studio.

After deleting all data, I manually added one record in one model to see if anything is downloading to app, and it is downloading this one record.  But if Amplify.Hub.listen does not detect a dispatched ready, then no local changes are synched to the cloud.

I’ve recently updated Amplify from version 0.6 to 1.4, and Flutter to 3.13.5 stable, not sure if these updates caused this issue or not.

My Flutter Doctor info:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.5 on channel stable at /Users/stephen/developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12fccda598 (6 days ago), 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
    • Engine revision bd986c5ed2
    • Dart version 3.1.2
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/stephen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile)
    • 3742B3F5-F361-412A-937A-CE78A2F18878
    • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            
    • macos                                
    • darwin-arm64 • macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

Relavent pubspect.yaml info:

```
  amplify_flutter: ^1.0.0
  amplify_datastore: ^1.0.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: ^1.0.0
  amplify_authenticator: ^1.0.0
  amplify_api: ^1.0.0
  amplify_storage_s3: ^1.0.0
  uuid: ^3.0.7
```